# In a string i want to replace all words inside square bracket with its 3rd square block string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `" case 1 is good [phy][hu][get] my dog is [hy][iu][put]  [phy][hu][gotcha]"`

I want the result string as `" case 1 is good get my dog is [hy][iu][put]  gotcha "`

Basically, I want all the substrings of the format `[phy][.*][.*]` to be replaced with the content of the last (third) square bracket.

I tried using this regex pattern `"\[phy\]\.[^\]]*]\.\[(.*?(?=\]))]"` , but I am unable to think of a way that will solve my problem without having to iterate through each matching substring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
\[phy\]\[[^\]\[]*\]\[([^\]\[]*)\]
```

and replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GGInfW/1/) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%5Bphy%5C%5D%5C%5B%5B%5E%5C%5D%5C%5B%5D*%5C%5D%5C%5B(%5B%5E%5C%5D%5C%5B%5D*)%5C%5D):

[image]

**Details**

- `\[phy\]` - `[phy]` substring
- `\[` - `[` char
- `[^\]\[]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - a `]` char
- `\[` - `[` char
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` is its value in the replacement pattern) that matches zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - a `]` char

**Java  usage [demo](https://ideone.com/CfpaqC)**

```
String input = "case 1 is good [phy][hu][get] my dog is [hy][iu][put] [phy][hu][gotcha]";
String result = input.replaceAll("\\[phy]\\[[^\\]\\[]*]\\[([^\\]\\[]*)]", "$1");
System.out.println(result); 
// => case 1 is good get my dog is [hy][iu][put] gotcha
```